# Using ClosedXml giving not appropriate response

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

[image: API response]

I am using the ClosedXML library for generating Excel sheets. I am Installing the latest version of the ClosedXML. I created an XL Workbook and add a single sheet to it. after executing the API not give proper response.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.